# Return value from callback function inside another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, async-await

I have a function being called which needs to return a value. The value exists inside a callback function inside of the downloadOrders function. The issue is "go" (log in `post request`) is printed before "close" (log in `downloadOrders`). So I'm not able to return the encodedPdf value. What do I need to do?

```
app.post('/api/***', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const result = await orderServices.downloadOrders(data);
        console.log("go")
        if(result){
            res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(result));
        } else {
            res.status(400).send({err: 'Error creating PDF document.'});
        }
    } catch(err){
    }
});

async downloadOrders(data){
    try {

        let documents = ["sample.pdf"];
        const pdfStream = pdfmerger(documents);
        var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('merged-pdf.pdf');
        pdfStream.pipe(writeStream);
        pdfmerger(documents, 'merged-pdf.pdf');
        pdfStream.on('close', function(code){
            console.log("close")
            let encodedPdf = base64.base64Encode('merged-pdf.pdf');
            return encodedPdf;
        });

    } catch(err){
        console.log(err)
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see where "done" is being logged in your posted code.

Comment: @Jacob sorry I meant "close". I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `close` event in a `Promise` so you can await it.

```
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  pdfStream
    .on('error', reject)
    .on('close', function(code){
      let encodedPdf = base64.base64Encode('merged-pdf.pdf');
      resolve(encodedPdf);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the downloadOrders function in a promise too.

```
app.post('/api/***', (req, res) => {
    orderServices.downloadOrders(data).then((result)=> {
        console.log("go")
        if(result){
            res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(result));
        } else {
            res.status(400).send({err: 'Error creating PDF document.'});
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({err: 'Internal Server Error.'});
    });
});

const downloadOrders = function(data){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        let documents = ["sample.pdf"];
        const pdfStream = pdfmerger(documents);
        var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('merged-pdf.pdf');
        pdfStream.pipe(writeStream);
        pdfmerger(documents, 'merged-pdf.pdf');
        pdfStream.on('close', function(code){
            console.log("close")
            let encodedPdf = base64.base64Encode('merged-pdf.pdf');
            resolve(encodedPdf);
        });
        } catch(err){
          reject(err);
        }
    });
}
```